# SSIS expression blanks everything before an IF

Tags: ssis

I'm tyring to build an expression to handle a filename for a CSV which will change depending on which contract is being output.

In my example, **Contract1** needs an additional word adding to the file for their ETL process.

In testing this, I've found that an IF in an expression will blank the part of the expression before the IF and also evaluate the IF incorrectly.

For example, this expression works:

```
@[User::Contract] == "Contract1"? "Yes": "No"
```

This is set up like so:
[image: Working expression]

However, if I set up the following expression, the IF stops behaving as expected:

```
"Does the variable contain Contract1 " + @[User::Contract] == "Contract1"? "Yes": "No"
```

This simply returns "No", which is the IF evaluating incorrectly:
[image: Not working expression]

The only thing that changed was adding text before the IF.

Any suggestions on A) how to get around this and B) why this happens?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that it is concatenating your variable Contract before evaluating the IF statement. If you wrap your IF in parentheses you should return the full statement.

```
"Does the variable contain Contract1 " + (@[User::Contract] == "Contract1"? "Yes": "No")
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you.  I can't believe I didn't think to add brackets!